# How do I create an interface that requires the Class to create a member like Serializable does?

Tags: java

When implementing the Serializable interface in Java, I need to create a static final long serialVersionUID. How can I create my own Interface that creates this obligation to any class that implements it?

For instance,

```java
public class myStuff implements Serializable{
    // required to get rid of warning 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -403570729449249706L;
}
```

But I cannot work out how to add this functionality to my own interfaces?

Comment: why would you need this? if you need to create the same long ID, just have your interface extend Serializable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bunch of misunderstanding in this question.

> When implementing the Serializable interface in Java, I need to create a staic final long serialVersionUID.

No, you do not. Try it - go write a class, stick `implements Serializable` on it, *do not* add that `serialVersionUID`, and compile it with vanilla javac. You will find that [A] that compiles fine, and [B] no warnings are generated either.

Various linter tools (tools that add additional code cleanliness checks) incorrectly whine about having to add that field. There are times when that field is required, but on net you usually should not add it.

### What is that field even for?

The only time the field even comes up, is if you are attempting to serialize with version A of a class, and then deserialize it back when version B is on the classpath. (B being not the same as A, and in fact, so different that there are different signatures in them).

**This is extremely tricky** - what *does* it mean when the Person class which used to have `String name` now has a `PersonName name` instead, because name is now split into initials, partner name, nickname, and so on? You can't just add some `serialVersionUID` and pray the java serialization mechanism just knows what to do.

Because of that, the serialization mechanism by default will flat out refuse to deserialize into a class that has been changed (it changed a signature: a field or method was added/removed, or an existing method/field was renamed, or a field's erased type has been changed, or a method gained/lost parameters, or one of its parameters' erased type has been changed).

**This is correct** - almost always you can't 'just' deserialize into a changed version like that and almost always you need manual attention (use the `readObject` and such mechanisms to take control of the serialization mechanism).

Setting `serialVersionUID` is the mechanism to indicate to the java deserialization mechanism: Actually, just deserialize into this new version; leave any newly introduced field as `null / 0 / '\0' / false` - and ignore any values for old fields that no longer exist in the new version.

### There is no need for the field

All classes have a serialVersionUID, whether you have that field or not. Classes with an explicit sVU field have that as sVU, other classes have their calculated sVU. You can trivially see these with the `serialver` tool that is sitting right next to your `java` and `javac` executables.

### The proper way to do it

**If** (highly unlikely!) you need to serialize/deserialize between 2 different versions, **and** (even more unlikely!) you can 'get away' with having the deserializer simply try its best, then **write some test code that confirms this** (after all, your app would be broken if that fails), which means you must still have the old version of the class. So, just `serialver` it, and stick that serial version into your new version.

**That is the one and only circumstance a class should EVER have a `serialVersionUID` field**.

### More problems on the horizon

Java's baked in serialization mechanism is not particularly nice. Its API is riddled with structural typing which is bizarre (nothing else in java other than `main` and `agentmain` do this), and the format is not readable by anything except JVMs. In this modern world of microservices and web connected stuff, that's very limiting. As a consequence, serialization (as in, java's baked in stuff) is **not recommended**. Even OpenJDK team itself tends to downplay it or outright recommends against it.

Instead, serialize to [JSON](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or use [protobuf](https://protobuf.dev). These are formats readable from many platforms and make the act of serializing explicit.

### Fix your linter

Whatever is telling you 'oh no! You have a class that implements Serializable (often, not on purpose, for example `Exception` implements it, and thus all subtypes do, and yet you rarely if ever serialize exceptions), you must add a serialVersionUID field! - fix it. Turn off that warning.

### Nevermind all that, I just want to force implementors to have some field

Literally not possible in java. An interface **cannot** request that a subclass have a field, `static` members don't 'do' hierarchy in any way, and you can't override fields. In multiple fundamental-to-java-the-language ways, the notion of 'enforce a subtype to add a field' is utterly nonsensical. It's not just 'not possible', it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: “the format is not readable by anything except JVMs”—That’s not true. The format is documented and not parsed by the JVM.

Comment: When discussing serialization alternatives, it’s worth mentioning [XMLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) and [XMLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html).  They can represent data types far better than JSON can.